# Simple upper bound of sum of first m combinations

Tags: summation, combinations, upper-lower-bounds

There is a proof online which uses the following:

$$1 + n + {n\choose 2} + \ldots + {n \choose m} \leq n^m \quad \text{for } n,m\geq 2$$

Is there a name of this bound? Or a short proof anywhere? The ones given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205600/sum-of-first-k-combinations) are more 'advanced' since I believe this one is really loose.

The step is used at section 2.3 of [this](https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/MCC17/Papers/knapsack.pdf) file.

Comment: use induction for the prove!

Comment: Base case is easy. For the induction step, what can we do? 

if this holds for $m-1$, then we need to prove $n^m - {n \choose m} \geq n^{m-1}$, right? does it follow easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Following from your comment,
$${n \choose m} =\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-m+1)}{m(m-1)\cdots1}.$$
We can assume that $m \ge n/2$ (just for the next step!) (otherwise consider ${n \choose n-m}$) and when this is the case
$${n \choose m} = \frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-m+1)}{m(m-1)\cdots1} = \frac{n}{m} \cdot \frac{(n-1)\cdots(n-m+1)}{(m-1)\cdots1} \le 2 n^{m-1}.$$
This gives
$$n^{m-1} + {n\choose m} \le 3n^{m-1}$$
and so the conclusion holds for $n \ge 3$. It's easy to check the $n=2$ case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! One last question, how does this work:
$$\frac{n}{m} \cdot \frac{(n-1)\cdots(n-m+1)}{(m-1)\cdots1} \le 2 n^{m-1}.$$

Comment: $n/m \le 2$ by our assumption and for the other term there are $m-1$ terms in the numerator and each is less than $n$.

Comment: oh, that's very loose! But works :) Thanks so much!

Comment: No worries, glad to have helped :)